# Persuading cmake to find curses in MSYS2?

Tags: gcc, cmake, curses

I am trying to build this project https://github.com/ggerganov/hnterm in MSYS2 (or MINGW64, whatever works).

So, I'm opening a MSYS2 shell; and note this:

```
$ pacman -Ss curses | grep -A1 installed
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses 6.2-3 [installed]
    System V Release 4.0 curses emulation library (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-pdcurses 4.1.0-4 [installed]
    Curses library on the Win32 API (mingw-w64)
--
msys/cgdb 0.7.1-3 [installed]
    Curses-based interface to the GNU Debugger
--
msys/ncurses 6.2-1 (base) [installed]
    System V Release 4.0 curses emulation library
msys/ncurses-devel 6.2-1 (development) [installed]
    NCURSES headers and libraries
```

So, it seems I have `ncurses` for both MSYS2 and MINGW64. Here is a quick list of files that might be relevant:

```
$ find /c/msys64/ -name '*curses.[ahd]*'
/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/libpdcurses.dll
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses/curses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses/ncurses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/ncursesw/curses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/ncursesw/ncurses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/pdcurses/curses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/pdcurses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/python2.7/py_curses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.8/py_curses.h
/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libncurses.a
/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libpdcurses.a
/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libpdcurses.dll.a
/c/msys64/usr/include/curses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/ncurses/curses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/ncurses/ncurses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/ncurses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/ncursesw/curses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/ncursesw/ncurses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/python2.7/py_curses.h
/c/msys64/usr/include/python3.8/py_curses.h
/c/msys64/usr/lib/libcurses.a
/c/msys64/usr/lib/libcurses.dll.a
/c/msys64/usr/lib/libncurses.a
/c/msys64/usr/lib/libncurses.dll.a
/c/msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses.dll
```

Since I'm in MSYS shell, I get this for `cmake`:

```
$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake

$ cygpath -w `which cmake`
D:\msys64\usr\bin\cmake.exe
```

Ok, so then, I try to build the project - as in the README:

```
git clone https://github.com/ggerganov/hnterm --recursive
cd hnterm
mkdir build && cd build
```

... except, I try this `cmake` command:

```
$ cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" .. --debug-trycompile
debug trycompile on
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Git: C:/msys64/usr/bin/git.exe (found version "2.31.1")
-- Looking for cbreak in CURSES_NCURSES_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CURSES_NCURSES_LIBRARY
    linked by target "cmTC_858aa" in directory C:/src/hnterm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CheckLibraryExists.cmake:72 (try_compile):
  Failed to generate test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindCurses.cmake:161 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS)
  third-party/imtui/CMakeLists.txt:69 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/src/hnterm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

So, `CURSES_NCURSES_LIBRARY` is `NOTFOUND` - even if I should have it on my system?!

There is nothing whatsoever related to this problem in the referred log:

```
$ grep -i 'error\|curse' CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
```

... and there are no C++ source files in the failing temporary directory, either:

```
$ ls ./CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_858aa.dir
build.make  cmake_clean.cmake  compiler_depend.make  compiler_depend.ts  depend.make  DependInfo.cmake  flags.make  progress.make
```

Only hint for me is that `build.make` has some Makefile lines I might recognize:

```
cmTC_858aa.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_858aa.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.obj
cmTC_858aa.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_858aa.dir/build.make
        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --progress-dir=/D/src/hnterm_git/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking C executable cmTC_858aa.exe"
        /D/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -E rm -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_858aa.dir/objects.a
        /D/msys64/usr/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/cmTC_858aa.dir/objects.a $(cmTC_858aa_OBJECTS) $(cmTC_858aa_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS)
        /D/msys64/usr/bin/gcc.exe  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=cbreak -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/cmTC_858aa.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o cmTC_858aa.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_858aa.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lCURSES_NCURSES_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

So, apparently linking step is separate from compilation, and where there should have been `-lncurses` in the `gcc` linker call, it says `-lCURSES_NCURSES_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND`.

So, how can I persuade `cmake` here to find the right `curses` library?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I got somewhere, but it is weird.

Anyways, I used the `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ...` command, because cmake originally wanted to make Visual Studio build; which should have been weird, for a MSYS shell.

And since the program I'm trying to compile seemed to want to do a static build, I tried referencing one of the static libs directly (after using a bit of `cmake-gui` to find the right option name):

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCURSES_NCURSES_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libncurses.a .. --debug-trycompile
```

This passes for ncurses, but then curl becomes a problem, then ssl etc.

Then, this comes up: I use the MSYS shell through ConEmu; and since I have a problem pasting commands like this, I finally decide to open the normal MSYS shell (that comes with MSYS2) - and I realize, it complains, "CMake Error: Could not create named generator MSYS Makefiles"!

Wait, what? It just generated those, in the same shell ?!

So, this is one of the most bizarre things I've seen:

normal MSYS2 MSYS bash says:

```
$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.20.1 ...

$ cygpath -w `which cmake`
C:\msys64\usr\bin\cmake.exe
```

And the ConEmu MSYS2 MSYS bash says:

```
$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.20.1 ...

$ cygpath -w `which cmake`
C:\msys64\usr\bin\cmake.exe
```

So the `cmake` program called in both cases, is the same -- HOWEVER:

ConEmu MSYS2 MSYS bash says:

```
$ cmake --help | awk '$0 == "Generators" {i=1};i'
Generators

The following generators are available on this platform (* marks default):
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
* Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
...
```

And the normal MSYS2 MSYS bash says:

```
$ cmake --help | awk '$0 == "Generators" {i=1};i'
Generators

The following generators are available on this platform (* marks default):
* Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
```

So, for some reason, cmake in bash of MSYS2 MSYS runing under ConEmu, detects a Windows environment, and offers generators for that - but in the normal terminal for MSYS2 MSYS bash, then it offers generators for a Unix environment -- even if it is the same program!

So, once in the normal MSYS2 MSYS bash terminal, then I can just use `cmake ..` - and all libraries are found:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git.exe (found version "2.31.1")
-- Found Curses: /usr/lib/libcurses.dll.a
-- Looking for nodelay in /usr/lib/libncurses.dll.a
-- Looking for nodelay in /usr/lib/libncurses.dll.a - found
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/libcurl.dll.a (found version "7.76.1")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /c/src/hnterm/build
```

... and running `make` builds the C++ program fine. The weird thing now, is that it runs, but it doesn't work (no rendered characters) in the normal MSYS2 MSYS bash terminal (where it got compiled) - but it works fine in ConEmu MSYS2 MSYS bash terminal ?!?!

Oh well - at least problem solved, and one more thing to be careful about ...